# How to use js variable in scss?

Tags: javascript, sass, vite

In vite project, I defined an env variable in `.env`:

```
VITE_THEME=1
```

And I have a `variables.scss` file to define a variable:

```
$theme-color: red;
```

I can use `import.meta.env.VITE_THEME` to get `VITE_THEME` in js, but now I want to use it in `variables.scss` to change the `theme-color` like:

```
$theme-color: import.meta.env.VITE_THEME == 1 ? red : yellow;
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Did you have a look at `sass-loader` documentation ? It might be what [you're looking for](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/#additionaldata).

Comment: You can't do that. SASS is a CSS preprocessor, which means that all SASS specific information disapears when you compile it to CSS. You can create custom class and add an element with js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, you should use a CSS-in-JS library. CSS is not a programming language, and you shouldn't just fetch some data with it. Alternatively, you can conditionally add a class to the body tag in JS and configure styles in CSS depending on that. There are ways to compile your SCSS so that it gets some data from a file, but it won't be reactive. If you want to only change an element, you could just conditionally apply classes with the `style` attribute too.